# How to save two different forms at once in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two separate widgets namely, personal and address which both contains input fields.What I want to do is send these forms simultaneously to the server to the same url as these receives data from the server.However the widgets are supposed to be separated .Can anyone elaborate how I should carry it out? Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must input data from each field to List and send to server